# searching for a question that appeared on mse

Tags: discussion

Dear all,
I'm searching for a question asked some time ago on mse.  It was about the proof of something like the following statement: take a subset S of the unit square of area >1/2.  Then S contains the vertices of a right angle triangle.  There was a nice answer using integration, though I can't remember who posted it.

I've tried tag search using the mse search box, and a google search, to no avail.  Can anyone remember any more about the question?

NB it's possible I have the wrong site, and this was posted on mathoverflow - but I don't think so.

Comment: this can also be used: https://approach0.xyz/search/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was on MO. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56623/a-puzzle-about-finding-three-points-x-y-x-z-and-y-z-in-a-subset-of-a/

Comment: many thanks! ___